# Is there a SQL function to check if everything between two records match?

Tags: sql, ssms

I can't use an actual example, but here's an example of some data I might have:

NOTE: This is already ordered by the timestamp, with the oldest line on the first (top) row and the newest line on the last (bottom) row.

```
+------------+---------------------+----------------+-------------+
| Product ID |       Status        | Days in Status |    Team     |
+------------+---------------------+----------------+-------------+
| 1a         | designing           |              4 | Engineering |
| 1a         | gathering materials |              6 | Engineering |
| 1a         | creating            |             20 | Engineering |
| 1a         | testing function    |              5 | QA          |
| 1a         | testing usability   |             10 | QA          |
| 1a         | designing           |              4 | Engineering |
| 1a         | recreating          |              3 | Engineering |
| 1a         | testing usability   |              3 | QA          |
| 1a         | testing function    |              1 | QA          |
| 1a         | testing             |              4 | QA          |
+------------+---------------------+----------------+-------------+
```

In this example, I would want to find the number of days that product 1a has been with QA most recently (not the total number of days it's been with QA). That would be 3 + 1 + 4. I also want to find the number of days it's been with Engineering most recently. That would be 4 + 3 = 7.

Anyone have an idea of how to do this?

----------- edit here is a better example:

```
+------------+--------------+-----------------------+----------------+-------------+
| Product id |     date     |        status         | days in status |    team     |
+------------+--------------+-----------------------+----------------+-------------+
| 1a         | Jan 1 2020   | designing             |              4 | engineering |
| 1a         | Jan 5 2020   | gathering materials   |              4 | engineering |
| 1a         | Jan 9 2020   | creating              |              2 | engineering |
| 1a         | Jan 11 2020  | testing functionality |              3 | QA          |
| 1a         | Jan 14 2020  | testing usability     |              5 | QA          |
| 1a         | Jan 19 2020  | gathering materials   |              1 | engineering |
| 1a         | Jan 20 2020  | creating              |              3 | engineering |
| 1a         | Jan 23 2020  | testing functionality |              1 | QA          |
| 1a         | Jan 24 2020  | testing usability     |              1 | QA          |
+------------+--------------+-----------------------+----------------+-------------+
```

I want to get the number of days 1a was most recently with QA (1+1) and the number of days QA was waiting on engineering immediately before that (1+3)

Comment: Please define "most recently".  There is no column in your data that specifies the ordering.

Comment: oh, sorry about that. the oldest is in row one and the newest is in the final row

Comment: . . No such thing.  SQL tables are unordered.

Comment: There's no "row one" nor there's a "final raw". [Database tables are unsorted by nature.](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/08/the-natural-order-misconception/)

Comment: in my actual dataset, I have a bunch of timestamps and I already have them ordered by timestamp. I'll add an example that clearly shows this.

Comment: Please read the guidelines in the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want the last group, then you can use `not exists`:

```
select sum(days_in_status)
from t
where  not exists (select 1
                  from t
                  where t2.status <> t.status and t2.timestamp > t.timestamp
                 );
```

If you want the last QA group, then I would suggest:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by status order by seqnum - seqnum_2) as ranking
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (order by timestamp desc) as seqnum,
                   row_number() over (partition by status order by timestamp desc) as seqnum_2
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where status = 'QA' and ranking = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Now I know how to sessionize in a database supporting OLAP functions, let's try it here again.

We need a new session identifier, greater than the previous, every time the team changes over time, and then sum the days for the greatest session id we get.

```
WITH
-- your input, enriched by a timestamp ...
input(Product_ID,Status,Days_in_Status,Team,ts) AS (
          SELECT '1a','designing'          , 4,'Engineering',TIMESTAMP '2020-07-05 12:21:01'
UNION ALL SELECT '1a','gathering materials', 6,'Engineering',TIMESTAMP '2020-07-11 12:22:02'
UNION ALL SELECT '1a','creating'           ,20,'Engineering',TIMESTAMP '2020-07-31 12:23:03'
UNION ALL SELECT '1a','testing function'   , 5,'QA'         ,TIMESTAMP '2020-08-05 12:24:04'
UNION ALL SELECT '1a','testing usability'  ,10,'QA'         ,TIMESTAMP '2020-08-15 12:02:05'
UNION ALL SELECT '1a','designing'          , 4,'Engineering',TIMESTAMP '2020-08-19 12:03:06'
UNION ALL SELECT '1a','recreating'         , 3,'Engineering',TIMESTAMP '2020-08-22 12:04:07'
UNION ALL SELECT '1a','testing usability'  , 3,'QA'         ,TIMESTAMP '2020-08-25 12:05:08'
UNION ALL SELECT '1a','testing function'   , 1,'QA'         ,TIMESTAMP '2020-08-26 12:06:09'
UNION ALL SELECT '1a','testing'            , 4,'QA'         ,TIMESTAMP '2020-08-30 12:07:10'
)
-- end of your input. In the real query, replace the following comma with 'WITH'
,
-- A counter that is at 1 every time the team changes, else at 0
with_counter AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , CASE WHEN LAG(team) OVER(ORDER BY ts) <> team
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END AS counter
  FROM input
)
,
-- a running sum of the counter of the query just above, as session id ...
with_session AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , SUM(counter) OVER(ORDER BY ts) AS sessionid
  FROM with_counter
)
-- finally, group by the session id, and grab the last (biggest) session id.
-- LIMIT 1 in certain databases, 
-- in SQL server, you go 'SELECT TOP 1' instead of 'SELECT'
--   and do without the final LIMIT 1 clause at the end.
SELECT
  sessionid
, SUM(days_in_status)
FROM with_session
WHERE team='QA' -- don't know if this filter is needed ...
GROUP BY
  sessionid
ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 1;
-- out  sessionid | sum 
-- out -----------+-----
-- out          3 |   8
```